# software gui themes are lost

Tags: 12.04, gnome, themes, gui

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 at the moment and couple of days ago all of my software started to use ugly theme. Ubuntu menus are ok and still using ambiance theme but software guis are changed. I tried to change the themes but that didn't work. I don't know what is the cause of this and the solution, please advise.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: anyone? any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution on another site. what I did to fix :

```
sudo apt-get install gtk-theme-switch
```

Start the newly installed "gtk-theme-switch" then select the desired theme and voila problem fixed. Bu I still don't know what caused the problem in the first place.